# How do i zoom out so my google map fits my closest marker?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

i just made a script that uses the google maps api and it looks for the closest marker based on the center of your current map.

is there a way i can make the map zoom out until at least the closest marker is visible?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

ended up doing it myself.

with the folowing code

`while(!markermap.getBounds().contains(markerarray[closestindex].getPosition()))
    {
            zoom = markermap.getZoom();
            markermap.setZoom(zoom - 1);
    }`

Comment: Or use `map.fitBounds(bounds)` where `bounds` would be a `LatLngBounds` object that you extended with whatever point(s) you need the map to center on.